# Disk image copied to my SD card doesn't boot

Tags: boot, sd-card, disk-image

I'm following the tutorial *[Install Cubian](https://github.com/cubieplayer/cubian/wiki/Install-Cubian)* to copy Cubian to my SD card. And I'm using the following command as the tutorial suggested:

```
sudo dd if=Cubian-desktop-x1-a10-hdmi.img of=/dev/mmcblk0p1 bs=4096; sync
```

And I get the following output:

```
506880+0 records in
506880+0 records out
2076180480 bytes (2.1 GB) copied, 178.307 s, 11.6 MB/s
```

But the SD card won't boot, and when I check it the card seems to be empty. When I run `df`, I get the following (only 2% full; it's only a 4 GB card and the image is 2 GB, so it should be around 50%):

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1   3918780     44012   3874768   2% /media/mark/cubie
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image file will already contain partitions and a boot sector therefore you cannot copy it to a partition.  Instead you need to copy the image to the whole SD Card:

```
sudo dd if=Cubian-desktop-x1-a10-hdmi.img of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=4096; sync
```

Note the lack of `p1` at the end of the output file.

You could probably increase the block size too - try `bs=1M` instead of `bs=4096`.